Ubuntu installation problem , can't install Ubuntu 24
I have been using Ubuntu 22 from last few months and everything was smooth until I moved my laptop and it automatically rebooted and started showing kernal panic errors...
After few days of trying I removed the hard drive and formatted it completely and now after putting the drive back in I am trying to install Ubuntu again but when grub loads and I press install Ubuntu or any other option,it get stuck with a black screen and a white dash at top left corner.I have been trying to solve this issue form last 6 days but nothing is working....
I changed the usb flash drive as well but still nothing
Please help me out here

This question is similar to: Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Maybe something happened to the laptop when you moved it?
